# How to increase sensitivity/precision of Android's Gesture Overlay?

Tags: android, overlay, precision, gesture

I am making an application that needs to recognise user gestures, specifically letters the user draws, and then tells the user what letter (s)/he drew. Everything works well, except that several letters are similar and the Gestures library usually can't differentiate between similar letters. Is there any way to increase the sensitivity/precision of the Gesture overlay so that it can differentiate between similar gestures? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the score of the prediction, like `predictions.get(0).score > 5.0`.
Increase the score until you find a good score to your application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems one way might be to define multiple Gestures that give the same result, as seen [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).